# Why is there a object class defined within sealed class when I use Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code A is from the [official sample project](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples).

`Result<out R>` is a  sealed class, I'm very strange why `Loading` is defined as object class.

I think the Code B is more reasonable, is it right?

**Code A**

```
sealed class Result<out R> {
   data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
   data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
   object Loading : Result<Nothing>()

   override fun toString(): String {
      return when (this) {
         is Success<*> -> "Success[data=$data]"
         is Error -> "Error[exception=$exception]"
         Loading -> "Loading"
      }
   }
}
```

**Code B**

```
sealed class Result<out R> {
   data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
   data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
   data class Loading : Result<Nothing>()

   override fun toString(): String {
      return when (this) {
         is Success<*> -> "Success[data=$data]"
         is Error -> "Error[exception=$exception]"
         is Loading -> "Loading"
      }
   }
}
```

**Added Content:**

To Tenfour04 and a_local_nobody: Thanks!

The Android Studio can compile and run after I add `is` before `Loading -> "Loading"`  in Code C.

1:  What are differents between Code A and Code C?

2:  And more, In my mind, all types whithin sealed class should be the same, maybe they are all data class, or they are all object.
But Code A mix data class and object, and it's Ok, does it mean that I add even `Interface` whithin sealed class ?

**Code C**

```
sealed class Result<out R> {
   data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
   data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
   object Loading : Result<Nothing>()

   override fun toString(): String {
      return when (this) {
         is Success<*> -> "Success[data=$data]"
         is Error -> "Error[exception=$exception]"
         is Loading -> "Loading"     // I add "is"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no reason not to use an `object` for a class that doesn't have any properties (holds no state). `object` means you don't have to create multiple instances of it and you never have to worry about which instance you're looking at, so it's simpler. You don't have to call a constructor on it to get an instance, and there will never be more than one instance of it taking up memory.

Note that your `is Loading` check in Code B will still work if `Loading` is an `object`. `object`s are more versatile because `==` and `is` checks are both valid and effectively mean the same thing.

By the way (as mentioned before by @a_local_nobody), you cannot create a data class with no properties, although you could create a regular class.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, there is no difference with using `is` or equality comparison for an `object`. Since there can only be one instance of an `object`, then if something is that object, you know it’s the same instance and must therefore be equal. Code A and code C mean exactly the same thing. About question 2, you say in your mind they should be the same. I don’t know how to answer that. No, they don’t need to be the same. There’s no reason to restrict it. An interface can’t subclass a class, so it what you’re asking about isn’t possible.

Comment: However, you can also define sealed interfaces instead of sealed classes, and you could make an interface that extends a sealed interface, and that would work fine. Of course it would only make sense to define it if you were going to define at least two children of it.

Answer (score 1):

that won't work, because:

```
data class Loading : Result<Nothing>() <-- this isn't valid for a data class
```

Data classes must have at least one primary constructor parameter, presumably the author used an object there to avoid having to make use of a constructor value, compared to the others:

```
 data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>() <-- (val data: T)
 data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>() <-- (val exception: Exception)
```

which clearly require values

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?